# Django - OR filter on two fields, one of which is in related table

Tags: django, filter

I have two models: Post and User (the standard Django User model - thus not shown below)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # post_file = CloudinaryField(resource_type='video',blank=True)
    post_file = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=False,default="")
    user =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,default="")
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to filter Posts where either the post description or the User.user_name contains a search string.

e.g. search_crit ='erch'

Tried many approaches but the solution keeps evading me.

```
from django.db.models import Q

active_post_views = Post.objects.filter(active=True, approved=True).select_related('user')


matched_active_post_views = active_post_views.filter(
                Q(description__contains=search_crit) |
                Q(username__contains=search_crit)
            )
```

The above fails, so obviously not correct. It has a problem with the Q(username__contains=search_crit) portion of the filter. I have also tried Q(user_username__contains=search_crit), to no avail.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username is in the `user` field, so you filter with `user__username__contains=…`. You thus look "through" relations with two consecutive underscores (`__`):

```
matched_active_post_views = active_post_views.filter(
    Q(description__contains=search_crit) |
    Q(user__username__contains=search_crit)
)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you. However I get the following error: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: active, approved, coverfile, current_feed_play, date, description, user,...

Comment: @HolgerBehrens: but did you prepend it with `user__`, in `user__username__contains=...`?

Comment: double underscore? Yes - I tried both user__username__contains=search_crit and user_username__contains=search_crit. Just ot be sure I will copy your code...

Comment: Oi - operator problem. Thank you that solved it. Don't know what I did wrong